# Support for NLog 2.1

Tags: c#, nlog, common.logging

I want to upgrade to Nlog version 2.1. Which version of Common Logging library should I use?

I am currently using Common Logging version 2.0 with Nlog 2.0. I replaced NLog v2.0 with 2.1 but it does not work. Any help?

I get this error - Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Common.Logging.NLog20](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.NLog20/) but you'll have to add an assembly redirect :

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.2.0" newVersion="2.1.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

And your common logging config should look something like this :

```
<common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

---

Thankfully the nuget packages for common.logging and adapters has changed ([see here](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/wiki/Common.Logging-Packaging-and-Versions))  You should be able to use the Common.Logging.NLog21 libarary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added Common.Logging.NLog20. However under which section of the app.config should i add the assembly binding? Also should my application refer Common.Logging.dll v 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: 2.1.2, the assembly bindings come under <configuration><runtime>

Comment: Hi Gary thanks i I did the above said changes but i still get the same error - Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging' :(

Comment: What does the inner exception say?  do you have a reference to common.logging.nlog20

Comment: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for common/logging: Unable to create type 'Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter'

Comment: <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE"/>
        <arg key="configFile" value="Logging.config"/>
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

Comment: Thanks for your help we finally used same CommonLogging.dllv2.0 & CommonLogging.Nlogdllv2.0 with                       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding> and it worked